# Moving project from unity 4 to unity 5 - "The name someVar does not exist in the current context"

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

So i am trying to move my project from unity 4.6 to unity 5.3

I get this error (marked by //ERROR in 4  lines) that some of the variables in the script do not exist in current context.

```
#if ENABLE_4_6_FEATURES
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
#endif

public class MobilePaint : MonoBehaviour {
...
#if ENABLE_4_6_FEATURES
    public GameObject userInterface;
    public bool hideUIWhilePainting=true;
    private bool isUIVisible=true;
#endif


...
public void HideUI()
{
    if (!useNewUI) return;
    isUIVisible=false;//ERROR
    userInterface.SetActive(isUIVisible);//ERROR
}

public void ShowUI()
{
    if (!useNewUI) return;
    isUIVisible=true;//ERROR
    userInterface.SetActive(isUIVisible);//ERROR
}
```

The error is for 'isUIVisible' and 'userInterface'.

Has someone encountered this in unity 5 and can tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preprocessor directives used, #if ENABLE_4_6_FEATURES, is probably false here, hence those variables would not be defined. Try commenting out the preprocessor.

```
 //#if ENABLE_4_6_FEATURES
    public GameObject userInterface;
    public bool hideUIWhilePainting=true;
    private bool isUIVisible=true;
//#endif
```

Comment: You say, probably, I say for sure. You are completly right.